# How to change python from UCS2 to UCS4

Tags: python, unicode, compilation, ucs

I have a Python2.7 with UCS2 build installed on Ubuntu 12.10. I just want to recompile python with UCS4 or enable UCS4. How should I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use:

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

to configure the source to build with UCS4 support.

From the `./configure --help` output:

```
  --enable-unicode[=ucs[24]]
                          Enable Unicode strings (default is ucs2)
```

Comment: yeah I read that, but where exactly do I type ./configure? Should I install a new python version?

Comment: I presumed you already knew how to compile packages; either install Python from source (with `--prefix=/usr/local` to not interfere with the system Python) or [build your own deb file from the original Ubuntu package](http://superuser.com/questions/24326/how-to-modify-a-deb-package).