# Create Virtualenv in Ubuntu 14.04 having Python UCS4

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, ucs, ucs-4

I need to create a virtual environment on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.14 having UCS4 encoding. It seems that by default I get an UCS2. Is there a flag to pass to the virtualenv command in order to set the right encoding, or maybe it is a setting that I should change in a second step?

Comment: You have to [recompile python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575808/7976758) and reinstall all pip-installed binary packages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ucs4